# Eclipse IDE hello world problem

Tags: java, eclipse, jdk

I'm having problems running a simple java program "Hello world"

i had installed the Eclipse Java EE IDE from eclipse site
and before it i had installed jdk

[image]

[image]

[image]

btw im using ubuntu 14.04

Any ideas ?

Comment: This is an eclipse issue. You can try this solution [link](http://progrepo.blogspot.in/2012/10/eclipse-unable-to-find-ant-file-to-run.html)

Answer (score 0):

Open `Eclipse` ->  `Window`  -> `Preferences` -> `Java` -> `Installed JRE` -> Click `Add` -> Select `Standard VM` -> Window will open, enter this

`JRE home` : `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64`

`JRE name` : It will automatically fill with one name

`Next` -> Finish

Restart your `Eclipse` & you are good to go.